# How to share a file on Drive and allow only to download instead of ask for granting permissions?

Tags: google-drive

I wish I could share files with non owners but I don't wish to allow the users to ask for granting modification access. I triggers unwanted emails to a manager that wants to keep his e-mail as the document owner for marketing purposes but do not wish to be kept posted by users who doesn't fully understand that they are supposed only to download the files. Do anyone have any clue on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time it's not possible but instead of using the default URL you could replace `/view` by `/copy` this will make that the user will see a page showing a "Make a copy" button instead of the file and the button to request access.